# what is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos^n(n^2+\ln(n)) x^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I want to calculate the radius of convergence of the power series  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos^n(n^2+\ln(n)) x^n$$ so I tried to use Hadamard's formula, but the problem is how to calculate $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \cos(n^2+\ln(n))$.

Can someone help me?

Comment: $limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}{cos(n)}=1,$ can this help us here? (we have compound function)

Answer (score 2):

$|\cos(x)| \le 1$, so the radius of convergence is at least $1$.  Showing it is exactly $1$ will be somewhat harder.  I think you can use [van der Corput's difference theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#van_der_Corput.27s_difference_theorem) to show that
$n^2 + \ln(n)$ is uniformly distributed mod $2\pi$.

Comment: then, what's the radius?

Comment: This shows $\lim sup \cos(n^2+\ln(n)) = 1$, so the radius is $1$.